# Select type object from json?

Tags: c#, json, rest

I have a problem with correct parse object from json query. I read something about JObject. Now i have two Model for example like `Car` and `MotorBike`. Query result is:

```json
"Vehicles": 
 [
        {
            "Id": 1,
            "title": "test",
            "price": "4000",
            "type": "Car"
        },
        {
            "Id": 1,
            "title": "test",
            "price": "4000",
            "drivingLicenseCat" "A",
            "type": "MotorBike"
        }
    ]
```

how can i parse to custom model by `type`

Comment: The JSON posted has only one type: `Vehicle` with (sub)`Type` being a simple property of `Vehicle`

Comment: prepare your model matching each item in the array, parse for a list of such items. finally filter for the items of the desired type. I see no benefit of trying to parse just the items of some desired type. Parse all first and filter for the items you want (by type).

Answer (score 1):

How much control over the JSON do you have? If you are generating the JSON out of, say, web api correctly, it would come through more like:

```
"Vehicles": 
 [
        {
            "Id": 1,
            "title": "test",
            "price": "4000",
            "$type": "YourNamespace.Car, YourNamespace"
        },
        {
            "Id": 1,
            "title": "test",
            "price": "4000",
            "drivingLicenseCat" "A",
            "$type": "YourNamespace.MotorBike, YourNamespace"
        }
    ]
```

and then it would be automatically deserialized when you bring it in...

Ensure, in the model that you are serializing and sending out as JSON, that you mark it up like so:

```
[JsonProperty(ItemTypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All)]
```

This will add the type names to the objects as they are serialized. I should also note, that this is with Newtonsoft as your Json library. I'm not sure about the built-in Json.